# using expand_dims() on ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

Can I add a dimension to an image within `flow_from_directory()` pipeline or do I need to write my own implementation for this? Can I use it on ingested data post factum or does it pull images into the memory at the time of training?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generator pulls in the batches of images as need by model.fit so it does not try to store them all in memory to avoid an OOM(out of memory) error. The generator does have a preprocessing_function which I tried to use to expand the dimensions but it throws an error so that will not work. Guess you have to create your own generator to accomplish what you wish. Think what I show below will work

```
train_dir=r'c:\temp\people\test' # point this to your training directory
# put in your data into the ImageDataGenerator and flow_from_directory my images are 128,128,3 color images
train_gen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255).flow_from_directory( train_dir, target_size=(128, 128),
                                                                    batch_size=10, seed=123,
                                                                    class_mode='categorical', color_mode='rgb',shuffle=True)
def img_gen(input_gen,axis):  
    images, labels=next(train_gen) # get the next batch of images and labels
    images=np.expand_dims(images,axis=axis) # expand dimensions of the images
    yield (images, labels ) #  output a batch of tuples to model.fit
# showing dimension of images have been expanded    
images, labels=next(img_gen(train_gen, axis=4))
print (images.shape)
```

images will now have shape (10,128,128,3,1) where 10 was the batch size I used